# Partial upgrade to 16.04.3 LTS error cannot create wakeup

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

New to all this so be please be gentle!
I've run a partial upgrade to 16.04.3. I guess I should have investigated why I was offered a partial upgrade before doing it!
I now find that it fails to boot. The first error I see is ...

/etc/rc.local: cannot create /sys/bus/usb/devices/4-3/power/wakeup  directory nonexistent.

Ubuntu then starts in read-only to protect the file system.

I can start the system by using    sudo mount -o remount, rw /
and then                           sudo lightdm

I can see that there is no 4-3 directory in devices but if I try to create it I receive "operation not permitted."

Would this be the correct way to pursue the problem?  If so, how can I create the directory.

I did run fsck which came back clean.

UUID from fstab and blkid are as follows....

```
fstab

/dev/disk/by-uuid/FD0EFB4B320ABC20 /mnt/FD0EFB4B320ABC20 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,noauto 0 0

/dev/disk/by-uuid/11637A9FD34E470C /mnt/11637A9FD34E470C auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/0624ecdd-aa57-4fa8-afa9-3eafe1cf9af7 /mnt/0624ecdd-aa57-4fa8-afa9-3eafe1cf9af7 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

blkid

/dev/sda1: UUID="22931bea-2f79-4b32-91ea-7c4d454de2be" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000d17e3-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="2bd637ad-5212-456e-8ddc-ec3288eee703" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="000d17e3-05"
```

Comment: Probably /etc/fstab is not metting to UUID of your partitions. Please type _blkid_ and compare UUIDs with  /etc/fstab.

Comment: Thanks for that, Redbob.  They do appear to be totally different. I'll update my original question with the data,

Comment: Having edited fstab to match the UUID shown by blkid I now have a working system.  Thanks so much for your help, Redbob.  Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?  Or am I misinterpreting how this works!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is usually associated with a mismatch in the /etc/fstab file, which manages disk assembly on a Linux system, especially when one of the affected partitions is root (/). To solve this:

1. Boot recovery mode (or using a live-cd/usb);
2. `mount -o remount, rw /`
3. run  `blkid` to annotate the UUIDs of existing
   partitions;
4. edit `/etc/fstab`, updating the correct UUIDs.