# Does the root filesystem mounting happen in /init (initramfs)?

Tags: boot, kernel, mount, filesystem, initramfs

Device drivers and device initialization starts when the kernel goes through the initramfs bridge; the initramfs contains the initial modules needed to set up the devices including the storage device on which the real root filesystem resides.

My question is, does the `init` script in `initramfs` after loading the relevant modules into the kernel mount the root filesystem on `/`  in read-only mode `ro`?

Unfortunately, I can't read shell scripts, but it seems that `fsck` runs from `/init`, but I can't say with certainty.

Last but not least, where does the root filesystem get remounted in `rw` mode? Possibly in `/sbin/init`?

Comment: Do you mean your system is raising up with unwriteable root folder? If this is, look if your /etc/fstab matches to your partitions UUID. Look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/947407/partial-upgrade-to-16-04-3-lts-error-cannot-create-wakeup

Comment: Well /sbin/init in the initramfs would mount the "real root" and switch to it, unless it is pointed to a shell or so. It's not necessarily a shell script though. Neither would it necessarily mount it in ro mode and need a remount (you can instruct that with boot parameter `ro`/`rw`). If you instructed it to mount in ro mode, fsck on the "real root" is supposed to be performed after switching root and rw remount takes place after that. It is done by whatever handles the fstab as per it.

Comment: @TomYan It's a mayhem. I've unpacked initrd.img and there was no /sbin/init. There's only /init which is obviously executed once the kernel finishes device initialization. I could tell now, why it's boring to try to figure it out what fits where.

Comment: Actually I was wrong. There are `rdinit=` and `init=` for setting the init to run in initramfs root and real root. The fallback value for `rdinit=` is `/init`, while one of the fallback values for `init=` is `/sbin/init`.

Comment: `/init` is usually  a shell script in initramfs. I (think) after going through its lines, it mounts real the root filesystem. Basically this chain goes like this: `/init --> /sbin/init` where `/init` in initramfs and `/sbin/init` in the real filesystem.