# /boot 100% full | No solution from google would work

Tags: boot, kernel

Today I rebooted the server and I was greeted by

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

I was able to boot the machine again with this kernel: **4.4.0-66-generic**.

```
$ dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ^ii
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic       4.4.0-64.85  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic       4.4.0-66.87  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic       4.4.0-70.91  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic       4.4.0-71.92  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic       4.4.0-72.93  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic       4.4.0-75.96  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic       4.4.0-78.99  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic       4.4.0-79.100 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic       4.4.0-81.104 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic       4.4.0-83.106 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic 4.4.0-64.85  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic 4.4.0-66.87  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic 4.4.0-70.91  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic 4.4.0-71.92  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic 4.4.0-72.93  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic 4.4.0-75.96  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic 4.4.0-78.99  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic 4.4.0-79.100 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic 4.4.0-81.104 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

---

```
$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic
[sudo] password for plex:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-89-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-92-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

---

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-66 linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-70 linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-71 linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-72 linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-75 linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-78 linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-79 linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-81 linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-89 linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-89-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 9 not to upgrade.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/43.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 134 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 456942 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic_4.4.0-92.115_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic (4.4.0-92.115) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic_4.4.0-92.115_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-92-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic_4.4.0-89.112_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic (4.4.0-89.112) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic_4.4.0-89.112_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-89-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-89-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic_4.4.0-92.115_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic_4.4.0-89.112_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas to get `/boot` cleaned out?

How do I keep `/boot` clean?

First of all thanks for your help!

My fstab:

```
cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/plex--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=6eccf367-b7e4-4f71-8a57-95446df6f9de /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/plex--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0

//192.168.178.200/Music /music cifs credentials=/home/plex/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
//192.168.178.200/Movies /movies cifs credentials=/home/plex/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
//192.168.178.200/Series /series cifs credentials=/home/plex/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

My blkid:

```
blkid
/dev/sr0: UUID="2016-04-20-22-45-29-00" LABEL="Ubuntu-Server 16.04 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="4cbe268b" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sda1: UUID="6eccf367-b7e4-4f71-8a57-95446df6f9de" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="374a8805-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="ddN08f-uZQ3-Xl0c-eOHf-C041-0QOc-TAGIyR" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="374a8805-05"
/dev/mapper/plex--vg-root: UUID="ed2ad2ac-3112-47aa-8357-29d34b940f23" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/plex--vg-swap_1: UUID="352400a2-e8d6-4dbf-9248-a4adc04d1592" TYPE="swap"
```

My df -ih:

```
 df -ih
Filesystem                Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                        741K   457  741K    1% /dev
tmpfs                       746K   623  746K    1% /run
/dev/mapper/plex--vg-root    32M  1.6M   30M    6% /
tmpfs                       746K     3  746K    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       746K     3  746K    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                       746K    16  746K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                   122K   351  122K    1% /boot
//192.168.178.200/Series       0     0     0     - /series
//192.168.178.200/Music        0     0     0     - /music
//192.168.178.200/Movies       0     0     0     - /movies
tmpfs                       746K     4  746K    1% /run/user/1000
plex@plex:/boot$ df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                       2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      597M  8.3M  589M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/plex--vg-root  491G   38G  428G   9% /
tmpfs                      3.0G  8.0K  3.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                      3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                  472M  466M     0 100% /boot
//192.168.178.200/Series    46T   39T  7.7T  84% /series
//192.168.178.200/Music     46T   39T  7.3T  85% /music
//192.168.178.200/Movies    46T   39T  7.3T  85% /movies
tmpfs                      597M     0  597M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I've added df -h in the same pastebin. Also how do I format my outputs properly so they get displayed as Zanna edited it?

Comment: I've tried this but would not help me at all. Or did I miss anything?

Comment: Look if your /dev/sda is properly settled in /etc/fstab. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/947407/partial-upgrade-to-16-04-3-lts-error-cannot-create-wakeup

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit further? Rather new to ubuntu...

Comment: Well output of blkid matches what is in fstab, is that what you ment?

Comment: Can you **[edit]** your question to expand it with full details of all the possible solutions you tried? Right now it's unclear specifically what happened and which answers you have tried using. As for what @Redbob is suggesting, please include in your question the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `blkid` (those are two separate commands--you can run one after the other and paste all the text from the terminal into your question). Even if they match I think it may still be useful to examine it and, at the very least, it will unambiguously clarify that this isn't a duplicate of the 2nd question.

Comment: Can you also include the output of  `df -ih`?  There might be a chance that the inodes are all used up in the `/boot` partition.

Comment: Highlight a section of text that is copied from the terminal, and press ctrl-K - this indents the entire block 4 spaces, and signifies a code block.

Comment: I've added the info you've requested and formated it correctly. 

How am I supposed to remove older kernels, when it wont allow me?