# Stuck at Grub Recovery after trying to delete and expand some partition using GParted

Tags: grub2, partitioning, root, home-directory, resize

I have windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 dual booted on my device. I had re-installed Linux recently on the Linux partition. And when I re-installed it I accidentally set the /home partition to only 20 GB and I must have set the / partition as 120 GB. Now what I believe happened was that I made the home directory I had initially as the new root directory because after running Ubuntu I saw that I had an ext4 partition with some of my older files.

Well I didn't realise the mistake in the small size of the /home partition until sometime later. And then I searched on upon how to expand my home directory using GParted. So now I had this 120 GB of space which I though was just contained remnant user files from the previous Ubuntu installed. So I deleted the partition to make it unallocated space and then expanded my /home directory completely occupying that space. And now I am stuck at the grub recovery window on boot.

Again I am not sure if I had set the root on the 120 GB partition but that is my theory. And also if it is relevant I had a swap partition between the 20 GB and 120 GB partitions and after making the 120 GB unallocated I moved the swap partition to the end of the partition to bring the 20 GB and 120 GB spaces together. Below is the current partitions on the  disk.

Comment: If you had used two partitions to install / (root) & /home and deleted one, then you probably deleted /. Only fix then is a new install. With separate /home, I suggest 25GB for a new / , but only use something else install option and also choose to mount the existing /home but DO NOT check format or else it will be erased. Of course you have good backup just in case. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deleted your /root partition. So your system can't find it during boot. You have to make a new root partition and then install the system again.

Comment: Before reinstalling your system, I suggest you to inspect your partitions. Follow this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/947407/partial-upgrade-to-16-04-3-lts-error-cannot-create-wakeup/947521#947521