# How to Overcome a Failing Recovery Mode

Tags: boot, grub2, initramfs, recovery-mode

I use Dell XPS with Ubuntu 16.04. I have sent my computer to their so called premium service in order to fix a hardware problem. Once I receive it back, it does not start the OS. Instead, it shows GNU GRUB with the following options:

*Ubuntu

Advanced options for Ubuntu

System Setup

Restore Ubuntu 16.04 to factory state

So, I continued with Advanced options and go into recovery mode.
After hundreds of lines, it reached to a point where it says "Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:

```
-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)    
-Check rootdelay=...    
-Check  root=...    
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls/dev)    
ALERT! UUID=ba8e53e2-... does not exist. Dropping to a shell!    "
It provides BusyBox built-in shell with     
"(initramfs)"
```

I tried couple of online solutions. 
For instance, what shall I do after I `mount --all`? or How can I have a clean solution, basically? Because most of the stuff online address different cases and there is no generic solution as far as I see. Could we elaborate this problem via the help of other users?

Comment: Probably disks UUID are not corresponding to `/etc/fstab`. Look at [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947407/partial-upgrade-to-16-04-3-lts-error-cannot-create-wakeup)

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

1. Boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-USB then choose "Try Ubuntu"
2. Connect to the Internet
3. Open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter
       after each line):

   ```
       sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
       sudo apt-get update
       sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   ```

   This installs and runs Boot-Repair. Click "Recommended repair".
   After it has done its magic, write down the URL
   (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and
   check if you recovered access to your OSs and can boot normally
   /without dropping to shell/.
4. If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who may
   help you by email or forum. You can also review it yourself and look
   over possible errors.