# Ubuntu root mount failed and also fsck not found at initramfs

Tags: initramfs, fsck

```
fsck /dev/sda1  -->/bin/bash: Output: not found
```

[image]

Comment: Follow my answer [at this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947407/partial-upgrade-to-16-04-3-lts-error-cannot-create-wakeup/947521#947521), see if it works.

Comment: boot from a livecd, and paste the contents of et/fstab in your question. your root file system should be mounting as "/" not "/root"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove HDD from system connect it to another system on second SATA port alongside with that HDD and turn ON system

Open terminal

Find the device label of that HDD using

```
sudo lsblk
```

for example if it is `/dev/sda1` then run below command in terminal

If `fsck` is not working then try

```
sudo e2fsck -f -b 32768 -y /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Please cheak answer once again

Comment: e2fsck Checks and repairs a disk, as does fsck and -f and -b will cheak forcefully superblocks.

Comment: I have similar problem i can't even get e2fsck to work its not found too

Comment: @MayurBhandare Any other solution without removing HDD?   I'm getting a similar problem /bin/sh: fack: not found